# Amadeus API Error : You do not have permission to access this content

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amadeus

I'm new to Amadeus development.
I'm trying to develop an airline booking website. I'm using Amadeus Self service API's to get flights from searched term. Everything used to work fine, but from yesterday, if i call an api, I'm receiving error 403 forbidden, Invalid user. And I had a look into my Self Service workplace, It's throwing an error You do not have permission to access this content.

Any answers much appreciated.

Sample of my website is https://master.d3799dd2ybju3c.amplifyapp.com/.

Note: This is not the actual website, It's just a sample. For fetching airports i'm using my own data. It's not calling any backend api.

And once you please do reload the page again for good response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you renew your api token after every 30 minutes?  Have a look at the FAQ on their site.  Mainly ensure your API key isn't publicly available.   All else fails, contact Amadeus support.

Comment: I tried renewing my api key. Now it's responding with all other data except flights offer search.

Comment: Unfortunately the Flight Offers Search API is currently unstable. The technical team is working on providing a fix.

Comment: Thank's for the information.